# Multiple lists in a for loop, numpy shape command requiring list entry?

Tags: python, list, opencv

I created the following for loop

```
for ItemTemplate in ItemTemplates:
    x = 0
    self.needle_images.append(cv.imread(ItemTemplate, cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED))
    self.needle_widths.append(self.needle_images[x].shape[1])
    self.needle_heights.append(self.needle_images[x].shape[0])
    x = x+1
```

I originally tried to write the for loop like this:

```
for ItemTemplate in ItemTemplates:
    self.needle_images.append(cv.imread(ItemTemplate, cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED))
    self.needle_widths.append(self.needle_images.shape[1])
    self.needle_heights.append(self.needle_images.shape[0])
```

I was assuming I didn't need to add the list entries to this code and perhaps there is a better way to do this but my Python skills are very young.  The top example is fine and my code runs ok with it, but I am looking to see if there was a better way to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last two lines of the loop are always *using* the last image appended to `needle_images`. The index of the last item in a list is -1.

```
for ItemTemplate in ItemTemplates:
    self.needle_images.append(cv.imread(ItemTemplate, cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED))
    self.needle_widths.append(self.needle_images[-1].shape[1])
    self.needle_heights.append(self.needle_images[-1].shape[0])
```

Or just bite the bullet and assign the image to a name at the top of the loop.

```
for ItemTemplate in ItemTemplates:
    temp = cv.imread(ItemTemplate, cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    self.needle_images.append(temp)
    self.needle_widths.append(temp.shape[1])
    self.needle_heights.append(temp.shape[0])
```

Or even...

```
for ItemTemplate in ItemTemplates:
    temp = cv.imread(ItemTemplate, cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    w,h = temp.shape
    self.needle_images.append(temp)
    self.needle_widths.append(w)
    self.needle_heights.append(h)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you need to store the `image`, `width` and `height` in three lists since `image` already has the width and height as its `shape` member, which you are already using. I also wonder why your top example works, since `x` will always stay `0` and this way all the upcoming Images will have the size of the first Image. The second example clearly doesn't work since you try to take the `shape` member of an array.

### Changes I would make

if you need the index (`x` in your case) I would use the enumerate() function to get it:

```py
for x, ItemTemplate in enumerate(ItemTemplates):
    # x : index starting from 0
    ...
```

you could also first get the image into a local variable and then add it:

```py
for ItemTemplate in ItemTemplates:
    img = cv.imread(ItemTemplate, cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    self.needle_images.append(img)
    self.needle_widths.append(img.shape[0]) # if needing to store widths in own array
    ...
```

if you don't want to get the `width` and `height` from the `shape` member you could store the Image in an own class or dict, in two separate members `width` and `height` though this wouldn't make a big difference from just using the `shape`.
So if the for loop doesn't get more functionality, I would write:

```py
for ItemTemplate in ItemTemplates:
    self.needle_images.append(cv.imread(ItemTemplate, cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED))
```

and use the `shape` member for the size since you can always store the `shape` value in a local variable when using it later:

```py
for img in self.needle_images:
    width, height, channels = img.shape
    display.blit(img, (width, height)) # pseudo operation
    ...
```